# how to fetch a web page content from google api

Tags: javascript, google-api

Is there any Google API to fetch a web page's content ?
I know this can be done using Curl .

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: Are you looking for something that will return content and integrate it into to a web app, or some stand alone app. There's several options depending on your intended usage.

Comment: yeah . I want some API that will return content which I can use in web app. Could you guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a Google API for that. There are function in every web development language. Like in PHP you can use curl() or file_get_contents().

A Google API usually are client side, but I am quite sure you need a server side solution.